# Facebook Android SDK Wall Stream

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing an application for a client who wishes to display their Facebook wall posts in the application. The Facebook SDK examples do a wonderful job explaining how to allow users to sign in, but this is not the functionality I desire. I only wish to stream information from a single profile for all application instances without any users having to sign in. If anyone has done anything similar, I would appreciate your suggestions. I will gladly provide any additional details.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to embed one of the [social plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) inside a web view.  Otherwise, you could embed an application token inside the application and then make a graph api call to /pageid/feed and use the json result to show the feed entries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have investigated the Graph api's. My issues with using this approach, is the required URI, I am not sure how I would handle that in an android application.

Answer (score 0):

Your client can also create a page which is public and then just get its feed simply via RSS, no need to sign-in and no need for access token in this case. Url for RSS feed should be:

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID&format=rss20
```

hope this helps

Comment: This looks like what I need. I did test the url you provided and it didn't work as I was hoping. The 'PAGE_ID" should be replaced with the Facebook page ID I wish to get the feed from correct?

Comment: yes, there is also a link on the page wall called subscribe via RSS. the page should be public so anyone can subscribe to its feed whithout signup